# LLamada a un Procedimiento desde un Boton en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, stored-procedure, botón

espero puedan ayudarme, soy novato en Laravel y php y estoy con algunos temas de concepto que no logro entender.

Tengo una vista  index.blade.php que tiene 3 campos como imput y un boton que quiero que llame a un SP almacenado en la base de datos que recibe los tres parametros y llena una tabla.

index.blade.php

```
 <option value="{{$profesional->id}}">{{$profesional->apellido}}</option>
<input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="5" name="diadesde"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="6" name="diahasta"/>
<td colspan=3><a href="{{'gcalendario' }}" class="btn btn-info" style="text-align:right">Procesar</a></td>
```

Como le paso los parámetros y llamo a mi SP desde este botón?

Mi funcion seria esta:

```
 public function calenda()
    $sps = DB::select("call proc(?,?,?)",array(2,"2021/01/01","2021/01/31"));
    return view('gcalendario.index', compact('sps'));
```

Donde va en el controlador o en el modelo? y Como recibe los parametros y vuelvo a la vista?

web.php

```
Route::get('/',function () {
  return view('gcalendario/index');
});
Route::view('gcalendario/generar','gcalendario.generar');
```

Está correcta la ruta?

Les agradecería muchísimo, estoy intentando viendo videos y ejemplos pero no hay caso.

Comment: No veo por que debería ir en el modelo, no hace sentido que aparezca en dicha capa desde que estás usando al facade DB, por otro lado si quieres mandar datos de tu vista al método, entonces debe existir un request enviando esa información

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Entonces la función iria en el controlador?. Y para enviar por request deberia usar ajax?

Comment: Resuelto., mil gracias